# How to check installed libevent version?

Tags: java, libevent, centos6.5

I have two different versions of libevent on my Centos 6, libevent version 1.4 (system default) in `/usr/lib` and version 2.0.21 (built from scratch) in `/usr/local/lib` (I have come to this conclusion because of these files `libevent-1.4.so.2` and `libevent-2.0.so.5`). I need to check which is version is being used because I am getting this error `java: event.c:715: event_add: Assertion !(ev->ev_flags & ~(0xf000 | 0x9f))' failed` when I run a java application which is also dependent on some other libraries (which I am not aware of). So my initial assessment is that java or the dependent libraries calls libevent libraries. 
So my question is how to check which libevent is being used by the system and java?

Answer (score 5):

I think the more accurate question is which version of libevent was being linked to your java program during runtime. 
You can check which the OS Dynamic Linker Runtime Bindings by running `ldconfig -p | grep event`. 
Also, in my machine the libevent library files is installed in :
/usr/include/event2 and /usr/share/doc/libevent-2.1.8